# Do my Aarakocra's Talons really have a 150ft reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, unarmed-combat, reach, aarakocra, dnd-beyond

So, I just made an Aarakocra character in D&D Beyond, and the Unarmed Strike has a reach of 5 ft, but the Talons racial trait attack has a reach of 150 ft for some reason.

[image]

Is this correct, or is it some sort of bug in D&D Beyond?

It's a 5th level Monk, standard array of ability scores, no homebrew, no Critical Role, no play test content, and nothing edited.

Comment: Questions about game-adjacent tools are on topic here. Reopened. Those familiar with the D&D Beyond character editor tool, I'd suggest advising what action can/should be taken if this is in fact a bug.

Comment: Even if the subject matter of DNDBeyond is on-topic, the actual question as currently worded seems unanswerable - we don't know how DNDBeyond is coded and can't tell the asker *why* there's a bug. If the question is instead asking "Is this range correct, or is it a bug?", then *that* would be an answerable question.

Comment: @V2Blast I agree with your comment and edited to make that change. I think that is version is unarguably answerable while still matching the OP's intent.

Comment: @DerpwaldDuck If you don't approve of my edit, let me know or rollback the changes.

Comment: I [reported the bug](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/21926-aarakocras-talons-unarmed-strike-attack-has-reach). It seems to be fixed now. Example: [my aarakocra character's sheet](https://ddb.ac/characters/1552474/pDwNSp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The reach should be the same as for your unarmed strikes.

Here are the rules from the *Elemental Evil Player's Companion* for an aarakocra's talons.

> **Talons.** You are proficient with your unarmed strikes, which deal 1d4 slashing damage on a hit.

This means that the Aarakocra's talons *are* its unarmed strikes: an aarakocra makes unarmed strikes using its talons. The talons deal a different damage amount and damage type than normal for unarmed strikes, but they nonetheless are used to make unarmed strikes.

So the correct reach for the talons is the same as the reach for your unarmed strikes, which will be 5 ft as you suspected (in general, barring any other special features).

This is likely due to some sort of data entry/lookup bug in D&D Beyond, but only the developers could confirm that. It would be best to report this inaccuracy to the developers for correction. Regardless, treat your character's talons as having a 5 ft reach.

Comment: For reference, [here's D&D Beyond's Bugs & Support forum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support). I've reported the bug here: https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/21926-aarakocras-talons-unarmed-strike-attack-has-reach

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed now. Example: [my aarakocra character's sheet](https://ddb.ac/characters/1552474/pDwNSp)

Comment: Oh, and thank you for the nice answer! Clean and simple, told whats in the book and what officially counts, and thus what I experienced must be a bug. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many many many bugs in the updated dndbeyond.com character creator tool.  The new tool is superior to the old one in many wonderful ways, but it's also very much in beta.  But you can make it better!  Report the bug to [this thread](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/19570-mega-thread-character-sheet-revamp-bug-report?page=60#c1239).  The turnaround on bug fixes has been quite impressive - you might even find this error corrected within a week.

Comment: In fact, it was already fixed even before you answered, because I'd reported it earlier :P

Comment: @V2Blast They are *so fast*!